# Can not install mysqlclient in a OFFLINE CentOS7 server with ERROR message "not a supported wheel on this platform"

Tags: python, mysql, django, centos7, python-wheel

I am trying to install mysqlclient in a offline CentOS7 server, so that I can connect my Django site to a MariaDB

What I did was to download .wheel package "mysqlclient-2.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" from PyPI.
Then I run the code

`pip install mysqlclient-2.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

But received the following message

`mysqlclient-2.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`
[error message][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhqUD.png

I looked through all available answers and internet questions but did not able to find a similar problem. Could someone give me help?

Thank you very much

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the `-win_amd64` suffix mean that you downloaded a build for Windows? You most likely want to download the source distribution instead. From there, just follow the steps in `INSTALL.rst`.

Comment: Hi Brain, Thank you for point out! I am looking at the INSTALL.rst right now. Still have problem of how exactly to finish the install. But I will keep on searching and learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After following @Brain comment, I have solved the problem.

I went to PyPI and downloaded the .tar.gz file;

Uploaded the file to the offline server. Unzipped the file and followed the INSTALL.rst

Although building from the .tar.gz source code required some more efforts. Thanks